# Pairs of data to Classify[]

Tags: list-manipulation, machine-learning

Suppose I had the following data

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
```

How would I turn this into

```
b={{1,2,3}->4,{2,3,4}->5}
```

That is, transforming the data into rules where each class has a definition as the three before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

(Most[#] -> Last[#]) & /@ Partition[a, 4, 1]
```

> {{1, 2, 3} -> 4, {2, 3, 4} -> 5}

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, the 2nd argument to `Partition` is n+1; however, n must have a numeric (positive integer) value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
ruleTransformer[from___, to_] := {from} -> to
ruleTransformer @@@ Partition[Range[5], 4, 1]

(* {{1, 2, 3} -> 4, {2, 3, 4} -> 5} *)
```

`Partition` breaks the data into groups of `4`, with start of each group shifted by `1` from the previous.  We then apply the helper function `ruleTransformer`, which takes a list of arguments `from___` to be put into the beginning of the `Rule`, and a single argument `to_` to be put at the end of the rule.

We can accomplish the same thing (with a slight modification) with an anonymous 
`Function`:

```
Function[# -> Reverse[{##2}]] @@@ Reverse /@ Partition[Range[5], 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Developer`PartitionMap[Most@# -> Last@# &, a, 4, 1]
(* {{1, 2, 3} -> 4, {2, 3, 4} -> 5} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
♃ = {#, #[[0]] @@ (# /. #[[0]] -> (1 + {##} &))} &@(#[[;; 3]] -> #[[4]] &@#) &;

♃ @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
(* {{1, 2, 3} -> 4, {2, 3, 4} -> 5} *)
```

Comment: ... posted this separately since it belongs to a different ... well, species. In case some/most of your alphabetic keys are not functioning replace `♃` with `$`.